# Neural Networks in MATLAB, initial weights

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I made Neural Network in MATLAB with newff(...). When you train it with the same inputs and outputs, the training results are different on different runs. I understand that it is happening because the weights are different for each time I run it. My question is how to make initial weights to be the same each time I train my NN so I can get the same results? 
Also, is it possible to save some weights from training No1 and latter use it for training No2, and how?

Tnx

Comment: Do you want to actually train the neural network? If you use the same weights on each training cycle (i.e. the weights don't change), then there is no way for you to train the neural network... so what's your goal?

Comment: Yes, I do want to train the NN. In my .m file i create, train and simulate NN. But the best performance of the training of the network I get when I run it for the third time. So, my idea was to save weights from the second running and use those as initial weights next time (so I don't need to run it 3 times in a row).

Answer (score 6):

To [generate reproducible results](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/generate-random-numbers-that-are-repeatable.html), you need to manually set the random number generator to the same seed/state at the beginning of the code. This can be done in a [number of ways](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/updating-your-random-number-generator-syntax.html) (depending on what version of MATLAB you have):

The old style:

```
rand('twister',1234)
```

The updated style:

```
RandStream.setGlobalStream( RandStream('mt19937ar','Seed',1234) );
```

A [new function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html) was introduced in R2011a that simplifies the last call:

```
rng(1234,'twister')
```

The latter syntax is the recommended approach.

Answer (score 2):

As a side note, and not a direct answer, there's something called [Nguyen Widrow initialization and it's already implemented in Matlab's Neural Net toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/nnet/ref/initnw.html).

In my experience it works pretty well and helps the neural net converge faster.  I've found that it also makes the results more consistent too.  I recommend using it as well as the fixed random seed as per [Amro's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796374/neural-networks-in-matlab-initial-weights/7797635#7797635).

Comment: Chris is right, check carefully which kind of weights' initialization is used as default, because in the last versions of MATLAB the default is NOT a random initialization but the Nguyen Widrow init algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Different Matlab Neural networks toolbox results is because of two reasons: 1-random data division 2-random weight initialization

For different data division problem use function "divideblock" or "divideint" instead of "dividerand" like this:

`net.dividefcn='divideblock;`
 `net.divideparam.trainratio=.7;`
 `net.divideparam.valratio=.15;`
 `net.divideparam.testratio=.15;`

For random weight initialization problem, It seems (I'm not sure) all Matlab initialization functions ("initzero", "initlay”, "initwb”, “initnw”) are almost random. So you should force this functions produce similar results per call.

`RandStream.setGlobalStream (RandStream ('mrg32k3a','Seed', 1234));`

And then use one of them:

`net.initFcn='initlay';`
`net.layers{i}.initFcn='initnw';`

Comment: started to format your code, lost patience ;-) Please edit and remove the backtics yourself

Answer (score -1):

```
If you really want to have the weights before and after the training of NN you can use these codes :

for n1=4:8
    wb1=rand(n1,n_input);
    wb2=rand(n_output,n1);
    bb1=rand(n1,1);
    bb2=rand(n_output,1);

    wb=[wb1(:);wb2(:);bb1;bb2]';

    xlswrite(['weight' num2str(n1) '.xlsx'],wb,'Sheet1',num2str(n1));

end


if n1==4
        wb = xlsread(['weight' num2str(n1) '.xlsx']);
        i1 = n1*n_input;
        i2 = n_output*n1;
        i3 = n1;
        i4 = n_output;

        f1=wb(1:i1);
        f2=wb(i1+1:i1+i2);
        f3=wb(i1+i2+1:i1+i2+i3);
        f4=wb(i1+i2+i3+1:i1+i2+i3+i4);

        wb1=reshape(f1,n1,n_input);
        wb2=reshape(f2,n_output,n1);
        bb1=reshape(f3,n1,1);
        bb2=reshape(f4,n_output,1);

    elseif n1==5
        wb=xlsread(['weight' num2str(n1) '.xlsx']);
        i1=n1*n_input;
        i2=n_output*n1;
        i3=n1;
        i4=n_output;

        f1=wb(1:i1);
        f2=wb(i1+1:i1+i2);
        f3=wb(i1+i2+1:i1+i2+i3);
        f4=wb(i1+i2+i3+1:i1+i2+i3+i4);

        wb1=reshape(f1,n1,n_input);
        wb2=reshape(f2,n_output,n1);
        bb1=reshape(f3,n1,1);
        bb2=reshape(f4,n_output,1);

    elseif n1==6
        wb=xlsread(['weight' num2str(n1) '.xlsx']);
        i1=n1*n_input;
        i2=n_output*n1;
        i3=n1;
        i4=n_output;

        f1=wb(1:i1);
        f2=wb(i1+1:i1+i2);
        f3=wb(i1+i2+1:i1+i2+i3);
        f4=wb(i1+i2+i3+1:i1+i2+i3+i4);

        wb1=reshape(f1,n1,n_input);
        wb2=reshape(f2,n_output,n1);
        bb1=reshape(f3,n1,1);
        bb2=reshape(f4,n_output,1);

    elseif n1==7
        wb=xlsread(['weight' num2str(n1) '.xlsx']);
        i1=n1*n_input;
        i2=n_output*n1;
        i3=n1;
        i4=n_output;

        f1=wb(1:i1);
        f2=wb(i1+1:i1+i2);
        f3=wb(i1+i2+1:i1+i2+i3);
        f4=wb(i1+i2+i3+1:i1+i2+i3+i4);

        wb1=reshape(f1,n1,n_input);
        wb2=reshape(f2,n_output,n1);
        bb1=reshape(f3,n1,1);
        bb2=reshape(f4,n_output,1);

    elseif n1==8
        wb=xlsread(['weight' num2str(n1) '.xlsx']);
        i1=n1*n_input;
        i2=n_output*n1;
        i3=n1;
        i4=n_output;

        f1=wb(1:i1);
        f2=wb(i1+1:i1+i2);
        f3=wb(i1+i2+1:i1+i2+i3);
        f4=wb(i1+i2+i3+1:i1+i2+i3+i4);

        wb1=reshape(f1,n1,n_input);
        wb2=reshape(f2,n_output,n1);
        bb1=reshape(f3,n1,1);
        bb2=reshape(f4,n_output,1);
    end

    net = newff(inputs,targets,4,{'tansig','purelin'},'trainlm');
    n.IW{1,1}=wb1;
    n.LW{2,1}=wb2;
    n.b{1}=bb1;
    n.b{2}=bb2;


And after training for saving the network you want :

[net tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);

wb11=n.IW{1,1};
    wb22=n.LW{2,1};
    bb11=n.b{1};
    bb22=n.b{2};

    wbzz=[wb11(:);wb22(:);bb11;bb22]';

    xlswrite('weight.xlsx',wbzz,'Sheet1');
```