# Different weights for different classes in neural networks and how to use them after learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I trained a neural network using the Backpropagation algorithm. I ran the network 30 times manually, each time changing the inputs and the desired output. The outcome is that of a traditional classifier.

I tried it out with 3 different classifications. Since I ran the network 30 times with 10 inputs for each class I ended up with 3 distinct weights but the same classification had very similar weights with a very small amount of error. The network has therefore proven itself to have learned successfully.

My question is, now that the learning is complete and I have 3 distinct type of weights (1 for each classification), how could I use these in a regular feed forward network so it can classify the input automatically. I searched around to check if you can somewhat average out the weights but it looks like this is not possible. Some people mentioned [bootstrapping the data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56062/averaging-weights-learned-during-backpropogation):

Have I done something wrong during the backpropagation learning process? Or is there an extra step which needs to be done post the learning process with these different weights for different classes?

One way how I am imaging this is by implementing a regular feed forward network which will have all of these 3 types of weights. There will be 3 outputs and for any given input, one of the output neurons will fire which will result that the given input is mapped to that particular class.

The network architecture is as follows:

3 inputs, 2 hidden neurons, 1 output neuron

Thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK, the typical structure for such a classification problem would have 3 output neurons, with the training result `1,0,0` for the first class, `0,1,0` for the second and `0,0,1` for the third. The the classes "share" the hidden layers. The feed forward classification could then just pick the output neuron with the highest result. (You didn't say much about your network's structure, so this might be what you're doing already. If so, please clarify your question.)

Comment: You are saying that this should be done during the learning process? In my case I have only 1 output unit for the backpropagation network as I wanted to keep it simple. This way I simply provided the inputs and the desired output. Then I verified that the weights were actually in fact different for different classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not make sense if you only train one class in your neural network each time, since the hidden layer can make weight combinations to 'learn' which class the input data may belong to. Learn separately will make the weights independent. The network won't know which learned weight to use if a new test input is given.

Use a vector as the output to represent the three different classes, and train the data altogether.

**EDIT**
P.S, I don't think the link post you provide is relevant with your case. The question in that post arises from different weights initialization (randomly) in neural network training. Sometimes people apply [some seed methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796374/neural-networks-in-matlab-initial-weights) to make the weight learning reproducible to avoid such a problem.

Comment: As @nikkie also mentions mentions above, it makes no sense to train on the different classes separately. You want 3 output neurons and you feed in training data  for the 3 classes to the input nodes. You'll of course want as many input nodes as you have input variables. If you have enough hidden nodes and you're doing the training right, the NN will at least somewhat successfully output different values in the 3 output nodes.

Comment: So for training the data altogether, is this algorithm correct? 1: Set initial weights, 2: Run Backpropagation algorithm, 3: update the weights. Repeat 2 and 3 until all the inputs and their desired outputs have been processed. The final weights should be the correct weights for all classifications. Is this correct?

Comment: @seedeg in neural networks you have a cost function. So repeat 2 and 3 until (i)all your training samples are classified correctly, or (ii) the change of the cost function reaches a very negligible value. Mostly (i) will be satisfied in training process unless the cost function converges very slowly, then (ii) applies

Answer (score 0):

In addition to response by nikie, another possibility is to represent output as one (unique) output unit with continuous values. For example, ann classify for first class if output is in the [0, 1) interval, for second if is in the [1, 2) interval and third classes in [2, 3). This architecture is declared in letterature (and verified in my experience) to be less efficient that discrete represetnation with 3 neurons.